# Separate email content from signature

Tags: c#, email

Is there a way to separate email content (body text) from an added signature using IMap packages?

```
IEnumerable MailList = Client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
var email = Client.GetMessage(MailList[0]);
string body = email.Body;
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean signature like a bit of text that somebody puts on the bottom of an e-mail?

Comment: @John exactly .

Comment: That seems tricky since e-mails don't have a defined "signature" section. You'll need to first determine if an e-mail is html or plaintext, then in each format somehow figure out where the signature section starts. I guess you could look for common phrases people use in signatures, in HTML perhaps someone might be kind enough to give their signature element a surrounding div with an id (perhaps).

Comment: @John can you give me some code??.

Comment: I have no code for this. As arnt and I have said, this isn't by any means a particularly easy or foolproof task.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather difficult problem.

For text/plain, you can look for the line "-- " (three characters, including the trailing space). For text/html, you can look for the CSS classes gmail_signature and moz-signature. For all mail, you can look for trailing text that matches the trailing text of the previous message from the same address.

However, none of this is foolproof. Lots of HTML sigs don't use those CSS rules (Outlook, for example, uses no relevant CSS), lots of plaintext sigs don't use --, and lots of middlecrapware inserts text after the signature so the "trailing text" may not be the at the very end.

Comment: @mcy beginning thanks you for your replay, but i need to any trick for all emails (yahoo, gmail, outlook and other, like (at company..), pleas help me

Comment: There is no simple trick, the problem actually is difficult. You'll need a lot of test messages and unit tests to get good-quality results for this task.